# jQuery effect .fadeTo() with toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know the simplest way to toggle the `.fadeTo()` effect when someone click again on `Click Me!` button then it will reverse the process again. I mean just like the `.fadeToggle()` works or something like that. But using `.fadeToggle()` cause the div to disappear.

Here is my - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SjAkr/)

**HTML**

```
<button>Click Me!</button>
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 20px
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  $("div").fadeTo(400,0.4);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use following snippet:

### DEMO

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        this.toggle = !this.toggle;
        $("div").stop().fadeTo(400, this.toggle ? 0.4 : 1);
    });
});
```

Or usually better solution is to toggle a class instead:

### DEMO

CSS:

```
div {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms linear;
    transition: opacity 400ms linear;    
}

div.faded {
    opacity:.4;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("div").toggleClass('faded');
    });
});
```

Comment: Both Working... Thank you Very much! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!.... :)

Comment: Mary, if you are happy with this answer and it works as intended according to your question please mark it as the correct anwser :)

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler ,

```
 <button>fadeToggle p1</button>
 <p>This paragraph has a slow, linear fade.</p>
  <script>
   $( "button:first" ).click(function() {
     $( "p:first" ).fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: This method is great if you want to fade in and fade out an element, however with this method you cannot control the amount of the opacity.